# How to add multiple gradient from different angles

Tags: texturing

Trying to get this circular gradient. Ignore background, I only need this circular frame. Problem is with different angles, how to achieve something similiar?

[image]

Comment: You mean you want a circular gradient, as viewed from the top, on an irregular surface?

Comment: I want something like this. It's flat surface. Problem is, you see how it's not white to blue, from point A to point B. Instead it has on the bottom again blue, then some light blue. I assume it needs more separate gradient combined, but I'm not best with the blenders shaders.
Maybe it doesn't have to be circular, it could be that normal linear, but the shape of mesh is circular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the color you're asking about? Is this the sort of thing you mean?

[image]

.. 2 gradients in the dimensions of polar coordinates, *Length*, `r` and *Gradient > Radial*, `theta`, mixed, and overlaid with a little noise in ordinary (Object Space) Cartesian coordinates. The origin of this circle is at its center. You may need to offset with Vector >  *Mapping* if your circle isn't at the object origin:

[image]

However, if reproducing exact, but non-mathematical patterns, vertex-painting, or texture-painting into a nice rectilinear UV map, might be a better way to go?

Comment: That's right that, thanks for help.
Not a fan of texturing in Blender, so gonna try this and see how it goes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

hopefully this is what you wanted to have:

[image]

result:

[image]

you can adjust a few things here (just play around and you will find out).

If you change the colorramp stops you will notice that the edge of the colors are getting blurry (if you move them more far away from each other) and sharper if you move them close to each other.

If you move both color stops in the same direction you will see that the area is getting bigger or smaller.

The gradient textures are used to drive the mix factor value between the different colors.

The noise texture is just used for a bit of randomness for the input vector of the gradient so that it is not sharp but a bit random. By changing the scale, detail, roughness and distortion you will see what i mean.

Of course you can write a lot of text here to explain, but my personal experience is: Play around with the values and you will learn a lot more than reading texts ;)

Comment: Not actually what I asked for, but my questions wasn't clear enough. But this is also great way, probably gonna use something of this. Yeah, tweaking values is best way of learning, but I'm not fan of texturing in Blender so I needed some guides. Anyway thanks very much!